# get substring between a stringA and next stringB after stringA

Tags: java, substring

How can I get the portion of the line between `oid=` and the `,` that comes after from this string?

```
datatype=text, merged=true, title=Service, collapsed=true, filter={explicit=false, multiSelection=true, all=true}}, isCascading=false, disabled=false, instanceid=2D49C-C03A-21}], isPublic=null, oid=58f550fe3b143a902a0005b3, options={manual=true},
```

I have tried doing the following, however, it finds the first occurrence of `,` and so looks to find the data between index of `oid`, and index of `,` which happens to occur before it, and so errors out.

```
final String oid = response.substring(response.indexOf("oid=") + "oid=".length(), response.indexOf(","));
```

Comment: There's another version of `index(String)` which accepts another param ... what do you think could be its purpose? ...

Comment: Once you find the index of `oid`, you can start searching the string *from that index* (see Tom's comment).

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the tip. Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` to achieve this:

```
String text = "datatype=text, merged=true, title=Service, collapsed=true, filter={explicit=false, multiSelection=true, all=true}}, isCascading=false, disabled=false, instanceid=2D49C-C03A-21}], isPublic=null, oid=58f550fe3b143a902a0005b3, options={manual=true},";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("oid=([^,]+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}

>> 58f550fe3b143a902a0005b3
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:

```
String oid = new String("datatype=text, merged=true, title=Service, collapsed=true, filter={explicit=false, multiSelection=true, all=true}}, isCascading=false, disabled=false, instanceid=2D49C-C03A-21}], isPublic=null, oid=58f550fe3b143a902a0005b3, options={manual=true},");
     int startIndex = oid.indexOf("oid=") + "oid=".length();
     oid = oid.substring(startIndex);
     int endIndex = oid.indexOf(",");
     oid = oid.substring(0, endIndex);
     System.out.println(oid);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Tom, for the tip on the other variant of this API.

My answer

```
        final String startPattern = "oid=";
        final String endPattern = ",";
        int startPatternIndex = response.indexOf(startPattern) + startPattern.length();
        int endPatternIndex = response.indexOf(endPattern, startPatternIndex);
```